# how to export customer records with unencrypted password with magento

Tags: magento, passwords

I've looked around a bit for this and haven't yet been able to find a decent answer. it seems like it's not really possible. I'm working for a company and we are switching our cms from Magento to another one and we want to migrate our customer data from one to the other. the only problem is that when you export customers it doesn't export customer passwords. and if you do choose to export passwords it's all encrypted and stuff. is there any way at all to export a clear text password?

Answer (score 0):

No, that is not possible out of the box.

However you can store the clear text upon customer creation/editing via extra module, however, I will **not** recommend that.

As far as I remember Magento stores the Password as `md5` alongside with a hash, in the form of `<hash>:<salt>`, which should be readable by any decent CMS, regardless of technology involved.

Any more information on the CMS?